# Why is the bicycle isoline the same as the pedestrian isoline?

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to compare the three different types of isolines (car, bicycle, pedestrian) available via the HERE rest api. I noticed that the isoline I get for bicycle is always exactly the same as the one for pedestrian. Why is that?

This is the request URI I use (with a valid App ID obviously)

```
http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateisoline.json?app_id=xxx&app_code=xxx&start=geo!52.5,13.4&time=PT0H10M&mode=fastest;bicycle;traffic:disabled
```

I'm using it in a processing script so the actual request is done like this.

```
String[] rawJSONResultArray = loadStrings(apiString);
```

([Here's](http://www.processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html) what the `loadStrings()` function does)

Comment: Ask Nokia. Why ask us?

Comment: The nokia-location-api tag is specifically watched by nokia here developers. So this is more a question directed to them than to the whole community.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because whoever programmed it used the same rate of travel. You could proxy it by treating the bicycle rate as being about 3 times as fast as walking, and hence tripling the rate of travel...or the (effective) amount of travel time.